# parse the nested json have same attribute with jq streaming mode

Tags: json, streaming, jq

I want to parse the data from the below nested json file, but it has too many "keys" in the json, it makes hard to parse the data

```
{
  "jobname": {
    "keys": {
        "jobid":"E000295",
        "car":"BMW"
    },
    "property":{
        "doctype":"File",
        "areadesc":[
            {
                "areaid":"qaz",
                "weather":"hot",
            },
            {
                "areaid":"wsx",
                "weather":"code",
            },
            {
                "areaid":"edc",
                "weather":"hot",
            },
            {
                "areaid":"rfv",
                "weather":"hot",
            }
        ]
    },
    "toolJobs":[
        {
            "keys":{
                "toolid":"123"
            },
            "reports":[
                {
                    "keys":{
                        "oiltype":"a",
                        "oilcountry":"us"
                    },
                    "property":{"reportid":"001"},
                    "datas":[
                        {
                            "keys":{"areaid":"qaz"},
                            "data":[
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-01",
                                    "value": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-02",
                                    "value": 3
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "keys":{"areaid":"wsx"},
                            "data":[
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-03",
                                    "value": 5
                                },
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-04",
                                    "value": 7
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "keys":{
                        "oiltype":"b",
                        "oilcountry":"china"
                    },
                    "property":{"reportid":"002"},
                    "datas":[
                        {
                            "keys":{"areaid":"edc"},
                            "data":[
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-05",
                                    "value": 2
                                },
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-06",
                                    "value": 4
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "keys":{"areaid":"rfv"},
                            "data":[
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-07",
                                    "value": 6
                                },
                                {
                                    "time": "2021-01-08",
                                    "value": 8
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

until now, I can use the below code to get the basic result, but some columns do not have, such as oiltype, oilcountry, reportid, areaid

```
cat tmp1.json |  jq -cn --stream '
 [fromstream( 
   1|truncate_stream(inputs)
   | (.[0][:2] | index("keys")) as $ix 
   | if $ix then .[0] |= .[1+$ix:] 
     else (.[0] | index("toolJobs")) as $iy | (.[0][$iy:$iy+3] | index("keys")) as $iz
     | if $iz then .[0] |= .[1+$iy+$iz:]
       else (.[0] | index("data")) as $ik
       | if $ik then .[0] |= .[$ik:]
         else empty
         end
       end
     end 
  )] | .[0] as $header | .[1] as $tool | [.[2:][] | ($header+ $tool+.)] | .'
```

The result is

[
{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","toolid":"123","data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":1},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":3}]},
{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","toolid":"123","data":[{"time":"2021-01-03","value":5},{"time":"2021-01-04","value":7}]},
{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","toolid":"123","data":[{"time":"2021-01-05","value":2},{"time":"2021-01-06","value":4}]},
{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","toolid":"123","data":[{"time":"2021-01-07","value":6},{"time":"2021-01-08","value":8}]}]

I also try below code

```
cat tmp1.json |  jq -cn --stream '
 [fromstream( 
   1|truncate_stream(inputs)
   | (.[0][:2] | index("keys")) as $ix 
   | if $ix then .[0] |= .[1+$ix:] 
     else (.[0] | index("toolJobs")) as $iy | (.[0][$iy:$iy+3] | index("keys")) as $iz
     | if $iz then .[0] |= .[1+$iy+$iz:]
       else (.[0] | index("data")) as $ik
       | if $ik then .[0] |= .[$ik:]
         else (.[0] | index("reports")) as $iw | (.[0][$iw:$iw+3] | index("property")) as $ii
         | if $ii then (.[0] |= .[$iw+$ii:])
           else (.[0] | index("keys")) as $ij
           | if $ij then (.[0] |= .[$ij:])
             else empty
             end
           end
         end
       end
     end 
  )] | .[0] as $header | .[1] as $prjob | [.[2:][] | ($header + $prjob + .)] | .'
```

but the result is strange

[

{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","property":{"reportid":"001"},"toolid":"123","keys":{"oiltype":"a","oilcountry":"us","areaid":"qaz"},"data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":1},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":3}]},

{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","property":{"doctype":"File","areadesc":[{"areaid":"qaz","weather":"hot"},{"areaid":"wsx","weather":"code"},{"areaid":"edc","weather":"hot"},{"areaid":"rfv","weather":"hot"}]},"toolid":"123","keys":{"areaid":"wsx"},"data":[{"time":"2021-01-03","value":5},{"time":"2021-01-04","value":7}]},

{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","property":{"reportid":"002"},"toolid":"123","keys":{"oiltype":"b","oilcountry":"china","areaid":"edc"},"data":[{"time":"2021-01-05","value":2},{"time":"2021-01-06","value":4}]},

{"jobid":"E000295","car":"BMW","property":{"doctype":"File","areadesc":[{"areaid":"qaz","weather":"hot"},{"areaid":"wsx","weather":"code"},{"areaid":"edc","weather":"hot"},{"areaid":"rfv","weather":"hot"}]},"toolid":"123","keys":{"areaid":"rfv"},"data":[{"time":"2021-01-07","value":6},{"time":"2021-01-08","value":8}]}

]

Below is my expected result

```
[
    {
        "jobid":"E000295",
        "car":"BMW",
        "toolid":"123",
        "oiltype":"a",
        "oilcountry":"us",
        "reportid":"001",
        "areaid":"qaz",
        "data":[
            {
                "time": "2021-01-01",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "time": "2021-01-02",
                "value": 3
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "jobid":"E000295",
        "car":"BMW",
        "toolid":"123",
        "oiltype":"a",
        "oilcountry":"us",
        "reportid":"001",
        "areaid":"wsx",
        "data":[
            {
                "time": "2021-01-03",
                "value": 5
            },
            {
                "time": "2021-01-04",
                "value": 7
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "jobid":"E000295",
        "car":"BMW",
        "toolid":"123",
        "oiltype":"b",
        "oilcountry":"china",
        "reportid":"002",
        "areaid":"edc",
        "data":[
            {
                "time": "2021-01-05",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "time": "2021-01-06",
                "value": 4
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "jobid":"E000295",
        "car":"BMW",
        "toolid":"123",
        "oiltype":"b",
        "oilcountry":"china",
        "reportid":"002",
        "areaid":"rfv",
        "data":[
            {
                "time": "2021-01-07",
                "value": 6
            },
            {
                "time": "2021-01-08",
                "value": 8
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: If you have to use the --stream option because the original file is very large, then I would suggest you consider constructing a two-stage pipeline: in the first stage, use --stream to winnow the data, and in the second stage,  invoke jq without the --stream option so you can more easily restructure it.

Comment: I have an idea is to get "jobid", "car", "toolid" first, because, in the final dicts, they have the same value, then I can parse other columns together. finally, combine it, but the difficult point is to pull the different levels to  "data" level, ex: "toolid" pull back to "data" level , {"toolid":XXX, "data":[]}

Comment: Both the sample input and the expected output are not quite valid JSON. Please fix them, and clarify (a) whether you really need to use the --stream option at all; and is so, then (b) whether you can see your way to a two-step solution as outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input has been corrected, the following "regular" jq program produces the desired result:

```
[
 .jobname
 | (.keys + .toolJobs[].keys) as $one
 | .toolJobs[]
 | .keys as $two
 | .reports[]
 | (.keys + .property) as $three
 | .datas[]
 | (.keys + {data}) as $four
 | $one + $two + $three + $four
]
```

If your input is too large, you could reduce the memory requirements by creating a jq-to-jq pipeline, with the first invocation using the above program (or a --stream version of it) but with the outer brackets removed.